# How many inches are in 7.94 feet?

Tags: arithmetic, unit-of-measure

> Question: the height on my land is 7.94 feet noted by a surveyor on a Certificate of Elevation form.

In layman's terms, that is 7 feet and how many inches? or how much of an inch is it short of 8 feet? or 7.94 feet is 7 foot and 11 inches?

Don't know how to convert 7.94 feet into feet and inches. I know 7.94 feet is .06 short of 
8 feet. It is .06 feet the thickness of a credit card, two credit cards, 10 playing cards.

An example would help. Maybe something like 7 feet 11 7/8 inches.

Comment: The first thing one should do is figure out what is a foot and what is an inch. If you type 7.94 feet into google, instead of definition, the first thing google return is an converter between different units of length. If you select the unit on the right to inch, you get 95.28in. Sometimes, it is easier to get the answer yourself than waiting for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

7.94 feet is 7 feet plus 0.94 feet.

0.94 feet is $12\times 0.94=11.28$ inches.

Since $0.28\times 32\approx 9$ we can say 7.94 feet is $$7\,'11{\textstyle\frac{9}{32}}\!"$$

This means your land is 8 feet minus $\frac{23}{32}$ of an inch.

If you're only looking for the nearest $\frac{1}{16}$ of an inch, it's $$7\,'11{\textstyle\frac{1}{4}\!"}$$
which is 8 feet minus $\frac{3}{4}\!"$.

Comment: ... where the $\frac 9{32}$ are obtained from $0.28\cdot 32= 8.96\approx 9$.

Answer (score 1):

The fractional part is $0.94 \text{ foot} \times 12 \text{ inch/foot} = 11.28 \text{ inches}.$